# Drupal site having all broken links after migration from live server to a new developer laptop

Tags: drupal-6

I need to develop a part of a Drupal web site. I cloned the git repository and setup the settings.php. The site is showing and I am using a dump of the MySql DB from the live server. I am 99% sure that the dump has been created without clearing the cache first. ANY link in the site is not working, so don't tell me to go to /admin/ because I can't. I tried to clean the table with cache* name without success. I have .htaccess in place. What elae I have do to do have a Drupal site working okay?

I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: We need more information. How are links "not working"? Plain 404s? Is this an apache server? Are the VHosts properly configured?, is mod_rewrite enabled? Is the site in a subdirectory in which case you need to configure the base_url? Did you try going to /?q=admin/settings instead of /admin/settings?

Comment: Yes 404 error. I am on Apache. mod_rewrite is on. It is in a virtual host an the configuration is ok. It is just that Drupal is rubbish. Now I remember why I moved away from PHP. I tried for follow Drupal's code but it is a nightmare. They should learn what OOP is (although OOP support in PHP is rubbish too).

Comment: Yeah we all wish Drupal was as amazing as Rails. Meanwhile, though, you should recheck your configuration because it's most certainly not "ok".

Comment: Give examples with your Drupal bashing please. No your apache problems don't count. Doesn't knowing how to properly configure Apache to read a .htaccess file apply to Rails as well? The things we have to do to have a Drupal site is actually quite simple and should not take more than a few minutes, especially for a professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't type this all in a comment, so it is now an answer...

> ~ "It is just that Drupal is rubbish. Now I remember why I moved away from PHP. I tried for follow Drupal's code but it is a nightmare. They should learn what OOP is (although OOP support in PHP is rubbish too)."

That comment is un-constructive, contradicting, and comical, especially considering you haven't even put in the time to know how to provide ample info for others to answer this question.

With such little info, I'd guess that Alexander is on the right track in questioning around it being an issue with your system's rewrite config.

Here are some other questions you should either have provided answers for or tried debugging already before you start blaming the platform over your ability to troubleshoot it.

Are you able to login? if not, maybe with http://example.com/index.php?q=user/login?

Any errors in the apache log? Have you tried to turn on rewrite debugging, and then any errors being reported if so?

Is mod_rewrite enabled on your local environment for clean urls?

Is your Apache config setup to AllowOverride=All for the specific virtualhost so .htaccess will pick up?  If not, have you configured Apache to load that .htaccess file?

Is $base_url set correctly in the settings.php file?

What is the format the links are providing?

Have you tried disabling any custom modules via the system table?

Can you install a brand new instance of Drupal on the same system configured the same way successfully?

The platform you know well is usually going to seem much more elegant than the one you don't know much about at all.

Comment: I was AllowOverride All (without the equal sign). The issue with PHP and then Drupal is that you waste your time with the details without been able to do the job quickly. As a matter of fact Drupal is not OOP, not MVC, it does not have a ORM, it only has a DB abstraction layer support the DBMSs. Should I continue? No, I am wasting my time but thank you anyway.

Comment: Not sure of the significance of pointing out that drupal is not OOP. I'd say it has modified MVC support where node objects are the model, modules are the controller, and the node template and theme is the view. While not all OOP, there is still a very smart architecture that allows for rapid development to extend Drupal to make it do whatever you need it to, all while not touching the Core software. It would be interesting to see your complaints qualified to something tangible rather than simply that it's not OOP, MVC, etc...  By the way, YOUR PROBLEM WAS WITH APACHE, not PHP or Drupal.